# Want to do some/the wheeling?

Tags: grammar

1. Do you want to do some wheeling?
2. Do you want to do the wheeling?

We have been playing with a bike trailer several times already. If you want to play again, are both options correct?

Comment: How about this: "Hey, bud, wanna do some more wheeling?"

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "wheeling" used to mean "playing with a bike trailer".  It usually means "spinning, like a wheel" or "moving something, by means of a wheel".

Comment: Thank you stangdon. What you said is what I tried to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is appropriate if you haven't done any wheeling yet.

2 is appropriate only if there is a specific performance or act of "wheeling" you are referring to.  A contrived example where this would work is if you were on a movie set and had to perform a wheeling as part of the script.

The right thing to say is:

> Do you want to do more wheeling?

Comment: Thank you. You said "perfom a wheeling", then can it be said too: do you want to do a wheeling?

Comment: Only if your use of "wheeling" fits the how I explained in #2 above.  Your example doesn't fit.

Comment: Thank you. Since I don't understand what you mean by a soecific performance and act, I will continue some more. Can you say, " let's do the biking" and what does it mean?

Comment: You can do that.  It's equivalent to saying "Let's bike," but by saying *biking* instead of *bike* we are implying that it is a "thing" to be taken care of.  Perhaps there's a number of things to do and biking is one you want to cross off your list, or you have to complete biking before returning for some reason.  It would not be natural to say if something like that was not true.  These are just examples, there's other reasons why you'd want to turn a verb into a "thing" like this.

Comment: Ok. I don't get it again. Then can I say "let's do the skiing next week" ? I am considering it as a thing( I don't know how far you can interfer this though)

Comment: @JoeKim - Yes, you can say "the skiing" to mean "a particular act or instance of skiing" but it's not common.  For example, if you are filming a movie that has both skiing and hiking in it, you might say, "Let's film *the skiing* this week and *the hiking* next week", because you are referring to particular, discrete acts, like *the* skiing that we will be filming for the movie.  But you wouldn't say "Hey Joe, let's do a/the skiing this weekend", because you're just referring to the general activity.

Comment: Thank you. Then, you say "let's do the washing, the gardening", because those are particular acts, not general activity, and consider them as things in certain situations? I don't know how to differentiate the definitions.